# How do I make a Button to create a new spinner on click

Tags: android

I want to create a form that allows the user to choose as many languages he\she knows (at least one)
I don't want to create an infinite number of Spinner, I want to create a button ("+" button)
that when the user click on it it will create a new spinner that will allow the user to choose another language.
How can I do it?
tnx

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener()
{
    onClick(View v)
    {
        Spinner spinner = new Spinner(YourActivity.this);
        layout.addView(spinner);
    }
});
```

layout - your parent layout

Answer (score 0):

just implement the `Spinner` as well, but `setVisibility(GONE)` and when you click the button change the `visibility`

Comment: tnx, but how can I make as many spinners with visibility(GONE) as the user want?

Comment: ah ok, now I understand, It's possible to add spinners at runtime as well I think. Just make a layout in your view and In your java code, add a new Spinner to that layout

Answer (score 0):

you can fill your language data in an arry and set dialogs items with this array.

[image]

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(R.string.pick_color);
           .setItems(R.array.colors_array, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
               public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
               // The 'which' argument contains the index position
               // of the selected item
           }
    });
    return builder.create();
}
```